# how to single out certain names in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have this problem in SQL where the question is this: `List the sId and name of students that applied to “WSU” But not “U of O”.` and my attempt was this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sName, 
       student.sID 
FROM Student 
LEFT JOIN Apply ON Student.sID = Apply.sID 
WHERE (cName<>'U of O' and cName = 'WSU') 
ORDER BY sName ASC;
```

However this does not do the trick as it doesn't catch that some of the students had already applied to U of O.
MRE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS College
(
  State CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  cName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  enrollment INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cName)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Major
(
  major VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (major)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student
(
  sID INT NOT NULL,
  sName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  GPA FLOAT NOT NULL,
  sizeHS INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MinimumGPA
(
  minGPA FLOAT NOT NULL,
  cName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  major VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cName, major),
  FOREIGN KEY (cName) REFERENCES College(cName),
  FOREIGN KEY (major) REFERENCES Major(major)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS APPLY
(
  decision SET('Y', 'N') NOT NULL,
  sID INT NOT NULL,
  cName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  major VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sID, cName, major),
  FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES Student(sID),
  FOREIGN KEY (cName, major) REFERENCES MinimumGPA(cName, major)
);

INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (123, 'Amy', 3.90, 1000);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (234, 'Bob', 3.60, 1500);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (345, 'Craig', 3.50, 500);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (456, 'Doris', 3.90, 1000);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (543, 'Craig', 3.40, 2000);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (567, 'Edward', 2.90, 2000);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (654, 'Amy', 3.90, 1000);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (678, 'Fay', 3.80, 200);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (765, 'Jay', 2.90, 1500);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (789, 'Gary', 3.40, 800);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (876, 'Irene', 3.90, 400);
INSERT INTO Student (sId, sName, GPA, sizeHS) VALUES (987, 'Helen', 4.00, 800);

INSERT INTO College (cName, State, enrollment) VALUES ('Cornell', 'NY', 21000);
INSERT INTO College (cName, State, enrollment) VALUES ('MIT', 'MA', 10000);
INSERT INTO College (cName, State, enrollment) VALUES ('WSU', 'WA', 28000);
INSERT INTO College (cName, State, enrollment) VALUES ('U of O', 'OR', 25000);

INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('CS');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('EE');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('history');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('biology');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('bioengineering');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('psychology');
INSERT INTO Major (major) VALUES ('marine biology');

INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('WSU', 'CS', 3.75);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('WSU', 'EE', 3.5);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('WSU', 'history', 2.8);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('U of O', 'CS', 3.6);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('U of O', 'biology', 3.75);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('Cornell','bioengineering', 3.8);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('Cornell','CS', 3.4);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('Cornell','EE', 3.6);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('Cornell','history', 3.6);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('Cornell','psychology', 2.8);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('MIT', 'biology', 3.5);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('MIT', 'bioengineering', 3.5);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('MIT', 'CS', 3.9);
INSERT INTO MinimumGPA (cName, major, minGPA) VALUES ('MIT', 'marine biology', 3.5);

INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (123, 'Cornell', 'EE', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (123, 'WSU', 'CS', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (123, 'WSU', 'EE', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (123, 'U of O', 'CS', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (123, 'MIT', 'CS', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (234, 'U of O', 'biology', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (345, 'Cornell', 'bioengineering', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (345, 'Cornell', 'CS', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (345, 'Cornell', 'EE', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (345, 'MIT', 'bioengineering', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (543, 'MIT', 'CS', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (678, 'Cornell', 'history', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (678, 'Cornell', 'psychology', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (678, 'WSU', 'history', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (765, 'WSU', 'history', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (876, 'MIT', 'biology', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (876, 'MIT', 'marine biology', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (876, 'WSU', 'CS', 'N');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (987, 'WSU', 'CS', 'Y');
INSERT INTO Apply (sID, cName, major, decision) VALUES (987, 'U of O', 'CS', 'Y');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CollegeStats
(
  cName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  appCount INT NOT NULL,
  minGPA dec(3, 2) NOT NULL,
  maxGPA dec(3, 2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cName)
);
```

And then of course the function at the end that i am trying to work on:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sName, 
       student.sID 
FROM Student 
LEFT JOIN Apply ON Student.sID = Apply.sID 
WHERE (cName<>'U of O' and cName = 'WSU') 
ORDER BY sName ASC;
```

what i get:

```
'Amy', '123'
'Fay', '678'
'Helen', '987'
'Irene', '876'
'Jay', '765'
```

expected:

```
'Fay', '678'
'Irene', '876'
'Jay', '765'


SELECT * FROM Student RIGHT JOIN Apply ON Student.sID = Apply.sID ORDER BY sName ASC;
SELECT DISTINCT sName, student.sID FROM Student LEFT JOIN Apply ON Student.sID = Apply.sID WHERE (cName<>'U of O' and cName = 'WSU') ORDER BY sName ASC;
```

The relation above what i am trying to accomplish should very nicely list all of the schools and majors the students applied to.

Comment: Sorry everyone if you have already made any sort of efforts i forgot that i had done a dumb mistake and i have corrected it. The question is students who applied to WSU only and not U of O

Comment: Your problem is you are joining one apply row at a time and you make sure that this is 'WSU' and not 'U of O'. But you must look at different apply rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join. You want to see students? So, select from the students table. They shall meet criteria? Use a where clause. Straight-forward with `IN` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student 
WHERE sid IN (SELECT sid FROM apply WHERE cname = 'WSU')
  AND sid NOT IN (SELECT sid FROM apply WHERE cname = 'U of O')
ORDER BY sName ASC;
```

Comment: And this will automatically snag both the name and sID?

Comment: It selects complete student rows with all their data.

Comment: Oh it has to return only the student name and sID so would you instead of select * put sID, sName?

Comment: Yes, you'd change `SELECT *` to `SELECT sid, sname` of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXISTS` and not `EXISTS` which might perform faster for larger data. Is the same as @Thorsten Kettner answer , only replaced in with exists.

```
SELECT sID,sName
FROM Student 
WHERE EXISTS   ( SELECT sid 
                 FROM Apply 
                 WHERE Student.sID = Apply.sID 
                 AND  cname = 'WSU'
                 )
AND NOT EXISTS   ( SELECT sid 
                   FROM Apply 
                   WHERE Student.sID = Apply.sID  
                   AND cname = 'U of O'
                  )
ORDER BY sName ASC;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> sID   sName
> 678   Fay
> 876   Irene
> 765   Jay
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab08807e7860203579736a7f3411ae70)

Comment: I find it kind of horrible when a DBMS comes up with different execution plans for `EXISTS` and `IN`. But you are right, this can happen. Old MySQL versions were notorious for that. I consider `IN` causes more readable. But it's a decision to make.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If I'm not wrong exists only apply on `MySQL`

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.sID, s.sName
FROM Student s INNER JOIN Apply a
ON a.sID = s.sID 
WHERE a.cName IN ('WSU', 'U of O') 
GROUP BY s.sID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a.cName = 'U of O' THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY s.sName ASC;
```

or:

```
SELECT s.sID, s.sName
FROM Student s INNER JOIN Apply a
ON a.sID = s.sID 
GROUP BY s.sID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a.cName = 'WSU' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN a.cName = 'U of O' THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY s.sName ASC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6afa0247439a6fcdf281f3f351491ad2).

Comment: Thank you this is actually more of the answer i was looking for. Something about the logic that was going through my head at the time, I am clearly still learning DBMS. But this shows me that there is certainly more than one answer to the same question/task when thinking about the relational algebra for some question. This was more of the visual direction my thought process was heading.